# Add comboBox in a JTable for a DB foreign keys

Tags: java, combobox, foreign-keys, jtable, foreign-key-relationship

I am doing a DatabaseManager Proyect where I display all the data of a db table in a JTable. Now I want to insert a feature so that the foreign keys of a table are displayed as a ComboBox with the values of the foreign table. So I was wondering which is the most optimal way to do it, I know that the Column which represent the foreing key is going to be filled with comboBoxes with the exact same values, but every each of them will have a specific default starting value. Here is the code that I have right now to just fill the data without comboBoxes:

```
private Collection<Map<String, String>> allData;
Object[] rowToAdd = new Object[manager.get((String) DatabaseJList.getInstance().getSelectedObject()).getDataManager().getColumnNumber()];
for (Map<String, String> rowz: allData)
            {

                rowx = rowz.values();

                int i = 0;
                for (String str : rowx)
                { 
                    rowToAdd[i] = str;
                    i++;
                }
                tableModel.addRow(rowToAdd);
            }
```

So since rowToAdd is an array of Objects, can I just create a comboBox and put it inside?Any suggestions how to do this?

Thanks a lot everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You don't add the data to the model. You just specify that a combo box is to be used as the editor for the specific. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using a Combo Box as an Editor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox) for a working example.